# client server socket programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, multicastsocket

Hii all

I am novice in socket programming..

I had two programs. RECEIVE and SENDRECEIVE.

In RECEIVE I simply write the code for receiving data from  a program acting as server using resvfrom(.....) and in the later one I had written the code for  receiving some msg from  a program acting as server using resvfrom(.....) also i am sending same data back to that server program using sendto(......).

I am using linux machines with multicast address 224.0.0.5 and port 4545.

My program is running well but problem is that is:

first my RECEIVE program  is receiving data 
then my SENDRECEIVE program receiving and sending data.

but it runs infinety.....I enclosed my code in while(1){.......}.

now what is the prob????

Is my close (.....) socket is not called for  SENDRECEIVE program.

If yes  how will i close my socket using which conditions  so that it will terminate after receiving msg from server and sending it back to RECEIVE program.....

"I cant send the entire code this time but the logic is ... after setsocketopt(.....)

```
while (1) 
//receiving from server  int
status=resvfrom(sock,buffer,MAxBUFFERSIZE,0,(struct
sockaddr )&addr,&socklen); {.....
{..... .. ..  }  //sending back to
server  int count=
sensto(sock,buffer,MAxBUFFERSIZE,0,(struct
sockaddr )&addr,&socklen);  {... .. .
}  
}
```

will u please help me as soon as
     possible..."

Comment: That slab of text is really hard to follow...

Comment: So the problem is you don't know how to break out of the while loop?  Can you post any of your code?

Comment: @user726750 welcome to SO! Please read the FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq and the How to ask section : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask so you can clean up your question. Also please see the formatting section if you need help with formatting your question : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: thanks for such a quick response.....i cant send the entire code this time but the logic is ... after setsocketopt(.....)        while (1)
//receiving from server
  int status=resvfrom(sock,buffer,MAxBUFFERSIZE,0,(struct sockaddr )&addr,&socklen);

{..........
}

//sending back to server
 int count= sensto(sock,buffer,MAxBUFFERSIZE,0,(struct sockaddr )&addr,&socklen);
{....
}
 will u please help me as soon as possible...
}

Comment: It's going to be signficantly easier to read that if you edit your question (click on the edit tag underneath it) and add it in to there.  Highlight it, then click on the {}, which formats code.

Comment: I think it's quite unlikely that this question can be answered in it's current state.  It's unclear what the current state of your application is, and what your desired outcome is.  I suggest rereading your question and asking yourself if *you* would have enough information to understand what your problem is from what you've written.  Questions to think about: Why have you got a while loop?  What messages do you want to flow between which applications, before which application closes which socket?

Comment: I simply want that after receiving my messages from links machin it will send to other application named RECEIVE and exit.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, but I'm trying to understand the question a bit better... From what I can tell, you've got a loop like this:

```
while (1) //receiving from server 
{
   int status=recvfrom(sock,buffer,MAxBUFFERSIZE,0,(struct sockaddr )&addr,&socklen);
   {..... {..... .. .. } //sending back to server 
   int count= sendto(sock,buffer,MAxBUFFERSIZE,0,(struct sockaddr )&addr,&socklen);
   {... .. . }
}
```

You want to escape from the loop after sending the response to the server... why can't you just do this:

```
   int status=recvfrom(sock,buffer,MAxBUFFERSIZE,0,(struct sockaddr )&addr,&socklen);
   {..... {..... .. .. } //sending back to server 
   int count= sendto(sock,buffer,MAxBUFFERSIZE,0,(struct sockaddr )&addr,&socklen);
   {... .. . }
```

Why do you need the while loop at all?